# How to pass a variable from config.js file to the java method in the feature file

Tags: karate

I have written a Java method which will accept certain args  like secret key, pem file etc and return a Token. when I call this method in my feature file and provide the 'secret key' and 'pem file location' it returns me a token which I use in the headers to pass the authentication. This scenarios work perfect.

Now the problem is we have different secret key and pem file for diff enviornment, is there a way where I can provide these variables in the config.js and use them in feature file while calling the Java method?

Feature file snippet below

- def token = Java.type('path.to.my.javaclass').javaMethod('secret_key', 'pemfilelocation')
- def req_headers = {Authorization: '#("Bearer " + token)'

This above is working perfectly fine.

Now if I use below config.js

function fn() {

```
var env = karate.env;
var config = {
    env: env,
   
    secretkey: 'secretkey',
    pemfileloc: 'pemfileloc'


}
if (!env) {
    env = 'dev';
}

if (env == 'dev') {
    config.secretkey = 'ewqewwqew'
    config.pemfileloc = 'src/test/java/location'
```

but this below is not working and the token generated is not correct.

Background:

- def secret = secretkey
- def pemfile = pemfileloc
- def token = Java.type('path.to.my.javaclass').javaMethod('#(secret)', #'(pemfile)')
- def req_headers = {Authorization: '#("Bearer " + token)'

---

can anyone please help how to pass the variable from the config.js to the java methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make this one change:

```
* def token = Java.type('path.to.my.javaclass').javaMethod(secret, pemfile)
```

Variables are that simple. Just keep in mind that whenever JS is happening in Karate (typically within round brackets) you can use variables "normally".

Also read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: Thanks a Lot Peter, it works like magic. This was so simple fix. :)